# How can I run not all robot test cases in team city, but just those with [tags] = A and/or [tags]=B

Tags: tags, continuous-integration, teamcity, robotframework

I have a list of robot test suites that contain more than 600 test case. 
I have about 50 test case with `[tags]= A`
How can i configure team city job to make it running only for `[tags]= A` without deleting other scripts

- PS1: the main goal is to not spend the whole 4 hours to see the full results of all jobs for all 600 test case but just around 30 minutes we can say if there is a critical problem we can see it in emergency.
- PS2: The tag is created for test cases with high severity and priority (the most critical test cases).

Comment: You just need to add `--include critical` in the script or command line you use to run robot.

Comment: And in team city how I set the configuration in the job?

Comment: Presumably you've already done that at least once. It's not clear what you're asking, since you're the one that configured team city in the first place. We can't guess what your configuration looks like.

Comment: @Bryan actually the idea is under design may be that&#39;s why I didn&#39;t describe it very well. The idea comes to me when I found the option [tags] in test cases written using robot framework so that I&#39;m asking if anyone has use that information of tags in configuration of teamcity.

Comment: It's still unclear what the problem is. You have to tell TeamCity what command to run and what arguments you give it. You just have to add the `--include` argument. It's no different than any other arguments for any other programs you run with TeamCity.

Comment: I update the question tell me if it is clear

Comment: The question is still not clear. TeamCity documentation shows how to configure commands with options. Why is that not good enough? What have you tried, and what were the results? https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/Command+Line

Comment: Actually you can consider that it will be my first time that I will make a change in the job configuration.

Comment: Perhaps your first step should be to talk to whomever original set up the job. They know more about your configuration than strangers on the internet.

Comment: I&#39;m developing a new idea I&#39;m seeking for some encouragement from stackoverflow community. I think that the question isn&#39;t as that strange may be some robot framework users faced the same thing. The main goal here is to help each other. 
Best regards

Comment: The problem is that you've asked something that can be answered by reading existing documentation, and haven't provided any details for why the most obvious solution isn't working for you. There's nothing special  you need to do for robot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go ahead by using --inlcude (or -i) as an argument during executing robot scripts.

Ex: robot -i A Test.robot

Note: Here, i am assuming "A" to be the tag for the 50 test cases, so that script will execute only those 50 test cases which are tagged as "A".

Similarly, if you want to execute test cases with multiple tags

robot -i A -i B Test.robot